# Integrate existing javascript project into angular

Tags: javascript, angular

From what I know, it is possible to integrate JavaScript libraries without the usage of npm by using e.g. `declare var importedLib`. However, we are trying to integrate a complete project which has a `main.js` and an `index.html` after build with grunt, so no npm or dist-libraries.

One way would be to drop the whole project into the src/assets folder and make a route to the project. But this would not make it possible to send variables to the project or interact in any way, since it's a standalone closed project.

Is there a way to integrate a standalone JavaScript project as an angular component?

Comment: What is existing `javascript` project? How does it work? Angular is component based architecture, so is your "existing" javascript re usable? Your question is too broad.

Comment: The answer is yes it can be done, and no we have no clue how to do it for your specific project. Please update the question with more details and examples of what you have tried.